# chrome.api* method to know if a tab has audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there a way in a chrome extension to know if a tab is currently playing an audio content (from Flash, `<audio>`, `<video>`, Web Audio API or any other way (Aka, when the "speaker" is in the tab title).

[Chrome Tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) seems to have no informations about that.

Comment: Finally, more than a year after, it"s possible :

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

boolean (optional) audible 
Since Chrome 45. Warning: this is the current Beta channel. Learn more.

Whether the tab has produced sound over the past couple of seconds (but it might not be heard if also muted). Equivalent to whether the speaker audio indicator is showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's none for that right now but you may want to file a feature request at http://crbug.com/new to let the chromium team know about your interest for it.

Comment: From what I see, this form is to submit an issue, is it really the right place to ask a new feature ?

Comment: crbug.com is the official ticket system of the Chromium projects. That's where bugs and feature requests live yes.

Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?q=label:Type-Feature

Comment: This answer is not longer valid, accepted answer should be updated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course: **since Chrome 45** you can use the [`audible` *Tab* property](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-Tab-audible).